# Why does "tee /tmp/my.log | my-binary" not exit immediately when my-binary is killed?

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

I have the following script:

my-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -o pipefail
tee /tmp/my.log | my-binary
```

...when run as follows:

```
$ cat my-data.txt | my-script.sh
```

I assume when my-binary crashes or is killed, the script *and* the copy of `tee` should exit immediately. However, while the shell itself exits, `tee` does not.

Comment: That's not enough to let someone else reproduce the issue. "Kill it" with which specific signal? Signals can be trapped, if `my-binary` chooses to handle it in a manner other than exiting.

Comment: (BTW, `pipefail` would ensure that the exit status indicated failure if *tee* failed but *my-binary* exited with success, but if it's `my-binary` that fails, `pipefail` has no effect whatsoever).

Comment: ...`set -e` isn't pertinent either, even though in most situations it's a source of [portability issues](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) and [general nonintuitiveness](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (skip the allegory if in a hurry and see the exercises).

Comment: I use "kill -9" and do find my-script.sh process is killed. But the tee process is still there.

Comment: Thank you -- that usefully clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1):

[The POSIX specification for `tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) specifies that if a write to a named operand (such as `/tmp/my.log`) fails, the `tee` command needs to continue writing to other outputs.

In order to fulfil this specification, common implementations of `tee` -- including the GNU implementation and the Busybox one -- ignore SIGPIPE altogether. This allows them to continue operation even if `/tmp/my.log` is a named pipe which closes early.

As a side effect of the SIGPIPE signal -- received when the other end of a FIFO aborts -- being ignored, `tee` does not immediately notice when its output to the stdin of `my-binary` is closed, but rather only notices later, when an attempted write fails.

---

If killing `tee` immediately is important, *and* you're running bash 4.4 or newer, I suggest the following implementation instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# replace stdin with a pipe from tee
exec < <(tee /tmp/my.log)

# collect PID for the process substitution; REQUIRES BASH 4.4 OR NEWER
tee_pid=$!
trap 'kill "$tee_pid"' EXIT

my-binary
```